# Can someone help me with the default code of tabToNextCell method of ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to override the default behaviour of **tabToNextCell** method of ag-grid. 
However, when I override this method, the default implementation does not work.

So I need to default implementation code so that I can tweak it a bit

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: I need the default code provided by ag-grid. So that I can tweak it as per my requirement. Basically, on tab out of the last cell in the grid, I want to add logic to add a new row

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic implementation of the default behavior of **tabToNextCell** function in ag-grid.

```
 tabToNextCell(params: TabToNextCellParams) {
    if (params.nextCellDef) {
      const result = {
        rowIndex: params.nextCellDef.rowIndex,
        column: params.nextCellDef.column,
        floating: params.nextCellDef.floating
      };
      return result;
    }
  }
```